# Is there a project management software for Ubuntu like Microsoft Project?

Tags: software-recommendation, project-management

I need a project management software for Ubuntu that has most (if not all) of the Microsoft Project features. Is something like this available today?

Comment: i run project in wine

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I can also suggest [planner](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/planner) [image: Install planner].  It's available in Ubuntu software-center.

[TaskJuggler](http://www.taskjuggler.org/) is really powerful but also a bit harder to use and is not available in Software Center.

Comment: Note that Gnome's Planner is capable of importing MS Project files.

Comment: For anyone who may wanna give a try to `TaskJuggler` like me: Don't waste time it is a total mess. Most of work is gonna be done via command-line.

Comment: Note that planner does not provide a way to copy tasks (essential in my opinion) and does not have the option to export the projects to any format that could be opened by any other software. A pity really, as everything else works well, and the output is nicer than other software out there.

Answer (score 4):

You can try [RationalPlan](http://www.rationalplan.com/). They have several project management products and starting with version 4.2 it is also available in the [Ubuntu Software Center](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/rationalplan-single/). And [RationalPlan Single](http://www.rationalplan.com/single-project-management-software.php) is even free on any Linux.

Answer (score 2):

There are many tools that are web-based and which are very usable through modern web browsers available for Ubuntu, like Firefox and Chromium/Google Chrome. Some are open source and you can install them on your own server, others are provided as Software as a Service, and will --- in most cases --- be provided on a subscription basis. These 'web applications' may provide a pretty comprehensive feature set similar to that of Microsoft Project.

If you are looking for a desktop application that resembles Microsoft Project, is free and open source, you could try OpenProj or GanttProject. They both have some of the features Microsoft Project provides, but opinion varies as to whether they can be considered suitable alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

There is []project-open[](http://www.project-open.org/en/install_ubuntu) as a multi-project server, that integrated with OpenProj/Project Libre and many other tools in order to form an open-source project management stack.